# Filtering duplicate model elements in django templates

Tags: html, django, django-models

It was necessary to weed out duplicate model elements on django. Removing identical elements is not suitable for me, but only filtering is suitable. My model includes albums and photos that are in those albums. If I send objects.all() to my template in views.py and try to display only my albums without repetition, then the album name is displayed in the template as many times as there are images in it. Is it possible to somehow check for a non-repeating output of my albums. PS: I am using sql database so objects.all().distinct('albom') doesn't seem to work for me...

My views.py (I want to filter the proverka function):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Image, Albom

def proverka(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect("/accounts/login/")
    else:
        albom = Image.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'Фото/Альбом.html', {'albom': albom})

def gallery_view(request, pk):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect("/accounts/login/")
    else:
        albom = Albom.objects.get(id=pk)
        return render(request, 'Фото/Фото.html', {'albom': albom})
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.proverka, name="albomm"),
    url(r'^Альбом/(?P<pk>\d+)', views.gallery_view, name="foto"),
]
```

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Albom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

def upload_gallery_image(instance, filename):
    return f"images/{instance.albom.name}/gallery/{filename}"

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_gallery_image)
    albom = models.ForeignKey(Albom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
```

My html template:

```
{% extends "Главная/Основа.html" %}

{% block albomm %}

{% for b in albom %}
  <a href="Альбом/{{ b.albom.id }}">{{ b.albom }}</a>
  <p>{{ b.albom.id }}</p>
{% endfor %}


<script>

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

I tried to filter with some solutions from the internet, but for some reason it doesn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5dF1.png)

Comment: Are you rendering every image in your template or do you just want to display a single image per album? Can you include where you render the image(s) in your template?

Comment: In this template, I don't want to render images. I just want to display on the screen the names of all the albums that contain some images.

Comment: This problem is precisely that the names are displayed, but they are repeated several times

Comment: Added an image with the problem

Comment: Why not query the `Albom` model and filter where there are related images - `albom = Albom.objects.filter(images__isnull=False).distinct()`. `distinct()` may not be required but I haven't tested

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, it does filter the titles, but if I send only the Album model, then the album id is no longer available to me. How to fix it?

Comment: That is, this <p>{{ b.name.id }}</p> no works here, but it is very important to me.

Comment: Maybe try `{{ b.id }}`?

Comment: Many thanks. It started working! I am a beginner and please do not judge strictly. I got an answer to a question. Thanks again!